# How to use Expression blend for WPF/Silverlight for beginners

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

Any one please provide me some video tutorials for expression blend beginners.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have so many video tutorials for the Expression blend designing.

http://www.lynda.com/Expression-Blend-tutorials/getting-started-with/384-2.html

http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc197141.aspx

http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/index.htm

You may also check the pluralsight website for your video tutorials..